# Spark Dataset join performance

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I receive a Dataset and I am required to `join` it with another Table. Hence the most simple solution that came to my mind was to create a second Dataset for the other table and perform the `joinWith`.

```scala
    def joinFunction(dogs: Dataset[Dog]): Dataset[(Dog, Cat)] = {
      val cats: Dataset[Cat] = spark.table("dev_db.cat").as[Cat]
      dogs.joinWith(cats, ...)
    }
```

Here my main concern is with **`spark.table("dev_db.cat")`**, as it feels like we are referring to all of the `cat` data as

```sql
    SELECT * FROM dev_db.cat
```

and then doing a `join` at a later stage. Or will the query optimizer directly perform the join with out referring to the whole table? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an explain and see if predicate push down is used. Then  you can judge your concern to be correct or not.

However, in general now, if no complex datatypes are used and/or datatype mismatches are not evident, then push down takes place. You can see that with simple createOrReplaceTempView as well. See https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/3741049972324885/4201913720573284/4413065072037724/latest.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions for your case:

**a.** If you have `where`, `filter`, `limit`, `take` etc operations try to apply them before joining the two datasets. Spark can't push down these kind of filters therefore you have to do by your own reducing as much as possible the amount of target records. [Here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Optimizer.html) an excellent source of information over the Spark optimizer.

**b.** Try to co-locate the datasets and minimize the shuffled data by using `repartition` function. The repartition should be based on the keys that participate in `join` i.e:

```
dogs.repartition(1024, "key_col1", "key_col2")
dogs.join(cats, Seq("key_col1", "key_col2"), "inner")
```

**c.** Try to use `broadcast` for the smaller dataset if you are sure that it can fit in memory (or increase the value of `spark.broadcast.blockSize`). This consists a certain boost for the performance of your Spark program since it will ensure the co-existense of two datasets within the same node.

If you can't apply any of the above then Spark doesn't have a way to know which records should be excluded and therefore will scan all the available rows from both datasets.

Comment: Well through repartitioning by including join's involved keys it is in most of cases guaranteed the co-location of the keys

Comment: I think that there many parts involved in the repartition/join operation hence I don't think easy to point only to one part of code. Although the repartition is a well known operation which does exactly that, for instance the `df.repartition(8, Seq("c1", "c2"))` will redistribute the combination of Hash(c1,c2) into 8 partitions. Then for the join Spark will try to co-locate the keys (c1, c2) for the second dataframe. This why shuffling exactly occurs because Spark tries to place all the data in the right place.

Comment: Forget I mentioned it. I was thinking of initial load. I am scrapping comments  as for repart and join of course so. However the thrust of the question  differes.